# rock drumming (swing?) pattern

Tags: drums, drum-kits, rock-n-roll

I've been curious about the drumming in ["Someday"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knU9gRUWCno) by The Strokes for some time now. Are the kick and snare going in double time?  Or is the tempo actually that fast and the hi hats are played in half time?  What is this style of drumming called?  Are there other examples of it?  What is the difference between the verse pattern and the chorus pattern? This song has a sort of light, swing feeling to it.  Is that because of the drumming or because of the strumming pattern of the rhythm guitar?  This song uses great chord progressions, but would not be nearly as good if played with a straight 8th note feel.

Thanks!

-286642

Comment: Rhythm guitar is not swinging at all. He's playing straight eights.

Comment: @Tim are you sure?  Please check this video (orange guitar) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRZm9lzlP_M

Comment: @Tim Isn't there some swing on the upbeats? And yes, everyone is accentuating the same things the hats and bass are, so that's a good candidate for the beat. It's not that fast though?

Comment: Still sounds like straight eights to me.

Comment: Definitely swung, not straight.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different questions in your post. But to try to answer your doubts, this is a very simple and standard rock beat. Snare on 2 & 4, hihat on each downbeat (1,2,3,4) and bass drum on 1, 2&, 4&.

[image]

To me it does sound like there is a noticeable swing to it.

You can play around with this online drum annotation tool, I transcribed the beat. You can move the swing factor and pick one where it feels right. (I transcribed in in half time because the tool needs it like that to apply the swing correctly).

https://gscribe.com/share/MCnkPbMEhWBm3qfw5